# How to have 2 split colors in the background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm using bootstrap as a launching pad, but I just cannot figure out how to make the 2 color background work. I'm trying to just use 2 divs and the bootstrap grid i.e:

[image: http://prntscr.com/3gwq5m]

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6" id="leftside">

</div>  

<div class="col-md-6" id="rightside">

</div>
```

Yet this way, I cannot get a h1 to sit in the middle!! Any solution? Sorry am beginner.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2AjGW/1/

Comment: And you want to have it on top of the elements centered?

Comment: Yes but I think Jayrow solved the problem :) just had to adjust the width to 100%

Comment: Wait what? Whats the point in having col-md-6 if the width is 100%??

Comment: Height* i mean height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a gradient and then use it as a normal background.

```
div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: linear-gradient(to right,   
    #9c9e9f 0%,
    #9c9e9f 50%,
    #33ccff 50%,
    #33ccff 100%);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FQ78n/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this by just using default Bootstrap classes (as far as I am aware). Try something like this:

```
<div class="row custom-row">

    <h1 class='custom-heading'>Heading</h1>

    <div class="col-md-6" id="leftside">

    </div>  

    <div class="col-md-6" id="rightside">

    </div>

</div>
```

with css:

```
.custom-row {
    position: relative;
}

.custom-heading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```